# Floating Action Button is translucent for some reason

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two Floating Action Buttons in my layout, but for some reason, the two buttons are semi-transparent.

[image]

I was wondering how to make the buttons solid? Here's the source code for the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_assignment_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/start_session_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/add_assignment_button"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
            app:useCompatPadding="true"></android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buttons are not actually translucent, but the listview is above them.

This is because you have placed the listview after the buttons in sequence in your xml and hence the list is drawn over your buttons.

Simple reverse the order of declaration in your xml and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

> Floating Action Button is translucent for some reason

Move your `FloatingActionButton` outside linear layout also no need to use of `LinearLayout`

make your layout like below

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_assignment_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/start_session_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/add_assignment_button"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]